# can my employer track my wife

Tags: networking, vpn

the question i have is more if a request for clarification from another question, 
"can my employer track my home network usage on another computer if i connect using vpn?".

I work on a company owned desktop that uses a vpn to connect to work from my home, using my private internet connection.

My wife is off one day a week while i work. she plays on her own private laptop through out the day (not on vpn)... facebook, email, netflix; girly stuff, right.

My concern is that my employer can see what she is doing when she's enjoying her day off. thus causing a topic of conversation for me and my employer.

What i gather from the other q&a topic above is that; in layman's terms, the desktop work computer opens a rabbit hole (vpn) and the only things that fall down the rabbit hole are direct actions performed by the desktop on the vpn (such as browsing history/keystrokes), thus my wife can enjoy her day off to her hearts content and my employer cannot see what she is doing. Thus releasing my concerns that my employer will be asking me why i am watching Netflix all day and not working.

Is my assessment of the nature of vpn's correct? Sorry for breaking this down so ridiculously, not everyone provides a layman's answer unless they know they are working with a layman. Thanks in advance.

Add on:
I do know the vpn is Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client version 2.5.2018. i sign to the VPN via the desktop. Not really sure if that makes a difference. I would assume that a router VPN would either be a new specialized router provided by the company (didn't get one) or something that would have to be installed via firmware.

I did look at the router settings and there are no entries within the "NAT -- Virtual Servers". i am not jumping to conclusions but there doesn't seem to be any other settings in the router that would lead me to believe that it would have firmware to support a VPN.

Comment: Short answer, No.

Comment: Company-owned laptop--they might have other means of monitoring usage besides the VPN.

Answer (score 2):

This question can not be accurately answered without more information - the key things which you need to discover are -

1. Does the VPN reside on your computer or the router.   If its your computer,
   and she is using a different PC you should be safe.
2. If the VPN resides on the router, you are in uncertain territory.  The
   strict answer here would be "yes", although if you can ascertain that 
   only routes to your companies network go through the VPN (this may or may
   not be the case), the practical answer would be "no" - however it would
   remain possible that a misconfiguration or deliberate action by your
   employer could jeopardise that connection.

If you can provide a network diagram of how everything connects, we can provide further advice.   Depending on the connection, it may be a matter of putting another router between the Internet and VPN, then connecting her PC into that router, thus bypassing the VPN for example.

Answer (score 1):

Simultaneous access to VPN and internal network resources can be done if split tunneling is enabled.  Which it probably isn't since they don't want a gateway into the private network.  So in real time, most likely no they can't see any network traffic if you're not connected to VPN.

*That being said,* it doesn't mean there isn't any management software installed on the corporate PC which periodically calls home.  I'm sure this could be configured to display lots of data, depending on what they're using.  For example, we collect application usage history at my job (for software licensing/auditing records; we're not interested in what you do.)